# JAAS login with unauthorised user

Tags: jakarta-ee, security, jaas

I've define two users: admin and user. 
now when I try to access admin pages using a no existing user, it send me back to the login page, so that's ok, 
But when I try to access admin pages using user's username and password, it send me to an error page and and if I try to access to the user page, It don't ask me to authenticate.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: Yes, and it is well explained, and I apologize for late reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.
There are 2 phases when a user accesses a protected resource:

1. Authentication – validating of a user credentials against a user repository
2. Authorization – checking that a user has permissions to access a resource.

When the user authentication failed a server requires to perform the authentication once again. In the case for the Form Authentication a user see the login page once again.
When the user authorization is failed a server shows authorization error page (generally it is HTTP 403 error). It is possible to customize the error page.